# Black region in Kinect depth image

Tags: 3d, kinect

[image: RGB Image]
[image: Depth Image]
*http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151605/Kinect-and-WPF-Getting-the-raw-and-depth-image-usi*

Black color in depth image comes because of large depths.
But why do we have black region in the places I marked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The holes on your TV/monitor are because the surface is too reflective; the infrared light from the Kinect's speckle pattern emitter doesn't get back to the Kinect's IR camera. The black halos around foreground objects like your head or shoulders are because to be scanned, a surface has to be visible to the pattern emitter and the IR camera at the same time. Surfaces immediately to the right and behind a foreground object are occluded to the pattern emitter, and surfaces immediately to the left and behind are occluded to the IR camera.

These halos get smaller when using a time-of-flight camera like the second-generation Kinect, because there the light emitter and camera are almost in the same spot.

Comment: What about the black dots on the almirah?

Comment: Some irregularities on a reflective surface, I suspect. If you hold a bright LED light to a metal armoire, you can see irregularities in the reflection. Some spots are too bright. Can also happen due to wet spots, oil stains, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a kinect expert but similar thing happens when you use too stiff height maps or projection. Kinect  works by projecting points (or another texture) so if the surface normal at the point is close enough to be perpendicular to the projection vector you will lose projection because it will be stretched "to the infinity". Another problem can arise if surface has too many "noise" and projection heavily distorted. Also surfaces with transparency or too glossy.

Probably you can fill those gaps by blending neighbours regions.

Comment: This is a good point. But if this would have been true, silhouettes must have appeared on both side of the person, on the boundary of the nose, sleeves etc. Also this doesn't justify the spots on the almirah.

Comment: @Shashwat it's glossy so most of the light from the pattern emitter getting reflected across reflection vector away from the camera.